# Design DIV using HTML5 and CSS3 with responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Please help me to create this image below using HTML5 and CSS3 with responsive design. Thanks guys!

Cheers :)

[image: HTML DIV]

Comment: Use bootstrap columns system

Comment: Hi EnriMR for suggestion but i dont want to use bootstrap.

Comment: Try Zurb Foundation. It's easy to use.

Comment: This is a bad 'question', and I have flagged it to close. StackOverflow is not a place where you can sign up, and ask people to code something for you. You have to try stuff yourself, and when you get stuck on an actual problem, you create a specific question for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Bootstrap, this code example could perform the same effect you need.

Try it in a browser:

```html
<div style="display: block; background-color:#0F0; width:100%; height: 50px;">1</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#F00; width:50%; height: 50px;">2</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#E00; width:50%; height: 50px;">3</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#110; width:25%; height: 50px;">4</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#220; width:25%; height: 50px;">5</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#330; width:25%; height: 50px;">6</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#440; width:25%; height: 50px;">7</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#006; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">8</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#007; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">9</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#008; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">10</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#006; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">11</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#009; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">12</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#006; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">13</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#00A; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">14</div><div style="display: inline-block; background-color:#00B; width:12.5%; height: 50px;">15</div>
```

Important things:

- To put several divs together, you need to specify the style option
  `display_ inline-block;` in each of them
- Div width must be in %